# how to convert duedate.date to duedate.datetime in rails after migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, scaffold

I have a small problem that i am facing.
When i started the project i used scaffold and defined due_date field as Date
now i want to do some date calculations. and i need to change the due_date field to Datetime .  Can sm1 help me with this
I know how to add new fields to table and delete but i am stuck at changing the attribute of already existing Model.

I have tried everything. Please let me know if there is any special code i can run in terminal to edit the attribute and create migration file.

P.s- Someone told me changing the schema file is bad. so i cant edit it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first generate the migration

```
 rails g migration change_date_format_in_my_table
```

then inside your migration file add

```
  def up
    change_column :my_table, :my_column, :datetime
  end

  def down
    change_column :my_table, :my_column, :date
  end
```

run your migration and its done. :)

Comment: yes, my_table is your table name, and same goes for my_column too

Comment: Thanks Ccr .  Worked like a charm.
Thanks for the quick reply btw.
:)

Comment: @ManishManandhar, if this help, please accept this ans